# Calculating YoY growth for daily volumes in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: sample Excel data]

I have 5 years of daily volume data. I want to create a new column in pandas dataframe where it produces the values of YoY Growth for that particular day. For e.g. compares 2018-01-01 with 2017-01-01, and 2019-01-01 compares with 2018-01-01

I have 364 records for each year (except for the year 2020 there are 365 days)

How can I create the column YoY_Growth as below in pandas dataframe.

Comment: How do you want to handle leap year data?  How do you want to handle data which appears in one year but may not appear in the next year for example because of weekends and/or holidays?  What have you tried?  Please see [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html). Always provide a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example").

Comment: I will try the solution provided  below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# It's more convenient to index the dataframe with the Date for our algorith,
df = df.set_index("Date")
is_leap_day = (df.index.month == 2) & (df.index.day == 29)

# Leap day is an edge case, since you can't find Feb 29 of the previous year.
# pandas handles this by shifting to Feb 28 of the previous year:
#   2020-02-29 -> 2019-02-28
#   2020-02-28 -> 2019-02-28
# This creates a duplicate for Feb 28. So we need to handle leap day separately.
volume_last_year = df.loc[~is_leap_day, "Volume"].shift(freq=pd.DateOffset(years=1))

# For non leap days
df["YoY_Growth"] = df["Volume"] / volume_last_year - 1

# For leap days
df.loc[is_leap_day, "YoY_Growth"] = (
    df.loc[is_leap_day, "Volume"] / volume_last_year.shift(freq=pd.DateOffset(days=1))
    - 1
)
```

Result (`Volume` was randomly generated):

```py
df.loc[["2019-01-01", "2019-02-28", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-28", "2020-02-29"], :]

            Volume  YoY_Growth
Date                          
2019-01-01      45         NaN
2019-02-28      23         NaN
2020-01-01      10   -0.777778 # = 10 / 45 - 1
2020-02-28      34    0.478261 # = 34 / 23 - 1
2020-02-29      76    2.304348 # = 76 / 23 - 1
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Quick question if you could help, please. From your data above, if for 2021-01-01 I need the YoY_Growth as the average of last two years. i.e. it would be (considering NaN is replaced with 0), (0-0.777778)/2 = -0.388. How would I edit the python logic?   In my data since I don't have future volumes for 2022, I can't calculate the YoY_Growth. This averaging would help me forecast YoY_Growth values.

Comment: In simple terms for 2022 it should not use this logic (df["Volume"] / volume_last_year - 1) but do an average of all previous years YoY_Growth values for same days.